# hashed search program endless loop

Tags: java, while-loop, hashtable

My code is getting stuck in the second while loop in my hash search method.  It seems like the conditions keep staying true, when they should eventually become false if the key is not in the dataset or if the key is found. Can someone help me find the bug?

Thanks

//////
this is the whole.. i been working on it.. still cant find the error.

```
    public void HashedSearch() 
    {
        HSAverageAccessTime       = 0;
        HSAverageCompSuc          = 0;
        HSAverageCompFailed       = 0;
        HSNumberKeysSuc           = 0;
        HSNumberKeysFailed        = 0;

        Initialize();

        int SearchKey;
        int TotalNumberOfComparisons;
        int address;
        int M;
        M = FindPrime();


        for(int i=0; i<NumberOfDataItems; i++)
        {

            address = OriginalArray[i] % M; 
            if (HashedArray[address]== -1)
                HashedArray[address]= OriginalArray[i];
            else 

            {
                address = (address+1) % M;

                while(HashedArray[address]!=-1)
                {

                    address=(address+1)%M;

                }

                HashedArray[address]=OriginalArray[i];

            }

        }

        System.out.println("after mapping" + M);
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        boolean found = false;

        for (int k = 0; k <NumberOfKeys; k++)
        { 

            found = false;
            SearchKey = KeysArray[k];
            TotalNumberOfComparisons = 0;


            address = KeysArray[k] % M;             
            //System.out.println("address" + address);

                //System.out.println(" inside if 1 --- address" + address);
            while ( HashedArray[address]!= SearchKey && HashedArray[address]!= -1)
            {
                if (HashedArray [address] == SearchKey)
                {
                    found = true;
                    TotalNumberOfComparisons++;
                    HSAverageCompSuc = HSAverageCompSuc + TotalNumberOfComparisons;
                    BSNumberKeysSuc ++;
                }
                else 
                {


                    System.out.println("Stuck after here");
                    HSAverageCompFailed = HSAverageCompFailed + TotalNumberOfComparisons;
                    HSNumberKeysFailed ++;

                        //address=(address+1)%M; 
                    address++;
                    }

                    System.out.println(" outside while --- found" + found);

                    //if(HashedArray[address] == SearchKey)
                        //found = true;
                    //else found = false;

                    //address=(address+1)%M;
                    //address++;
                }

            if(found)
            {
                HSAverageCompSuc = HSAverageCompSuc + TotalNumberOfComparisons;
                BSNumberKeysSuc ++;
            }
            else
            {
                HSAverageCompFailed = HSAverageCompFailed + TotalNumberOfComparisons;
                HSNumberKeysFailed ++;
            }
        }

        long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;

        if (NumberOfKeys != 0)
            HSAverageAccessTime = Math.round((estimatedTime/NumberOfKeys));
        else
            HSAverageAccessTime = 0;
        if(HSNumberKeysSuc != 0)
            HSAverageCompSuc        = Math.round (HSAverageCompSuc / HSNumberKeysSuc) ;
        else
            HSAverageCompSuc        = 0;
        if (HSNumberKeysFailed != 0)
            HSAverageCompFailed     = Math.round (HSAverageCompFailed / HSNumberKeysFailed) ;
        else
            HSNumberKeysFailed = 0;
        System.out.println("time after search" + estimatedTime);
        return; 
    }
```

Comment: What is M, wouldn't this loop forever if the key wasn't found?

Comment: There's a lot of code missing in your example. What are the types of `HashedArray`, `KeysArray` and `SearchKey`? Since you're using `==` and `!=` for comparison, I'm assuming them to be primitives, but if they're not, then you should use the `equals` method instead. Could you provide a more complete example?

Answer (score 0):

```java
while ( HashedArray[address]!= SearchKey && HashedArray[address]!= -1)
{
        address=(address+1)%M; 

}
```

Your loop never terminates if your **SearchKey** or **-1** is not in **HashedArray**. I cannot give you any more clarifications unless you post the complete code.

Answer (score 0):

@Bashir @KevinDiTraglia @Steinar

```
import javax.swing.*;
//File-related imports

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.math.*;

public class ArrayOperations
{
    // File Parameters
    String DataFilePath;
    String DataFileName;

    String KeysFilePath;
    String KeysFileName;

    int NumberOfDataItems;
    int NumberOfKeys     ;
    int N                ;
    int BucketHashArraySize;
    int NoBuckets;
    //Array

    int[] OriginalArray = new int[1000000];
    int[] SortedArray = new int[1000000];
    int[] HashedArray = new int[2000000];
    int[] BucketHashedArray = new int[2000000];
    int[] KeysArray   = new int[1000000];

    long SSAverageAccessTime;
    long SSAverageCompSuc   ;
    long SSAverageCompFailed;
    long SSNumberKeysSuc    ;
    long SSNumberKeysFailed ;

    long BSAverageAccessTime;
    long BSAverageCompSuc   ;
    long BSAverageCompFailed;
    long BSNumberKeysSuc    ;
    long BSNumberKeysFailed ;

    long HSAverageAccessTime;
    long HSAverageCompSuc   ;
    long HSAverageCompFailed;
    long HSNumberKeysSuc    ;
    long HSNumberKeysFailed ;




    public ArrayOperations()
    {   
        // File Parameters
        DataFilePath = null;
        DataFileName = null;

        KeysFilePath = null;
        KeysFileName = null;

        NumberOfDataItems=0;
        NumberOfKeys     =0;
        N                =0;
        BucketHashArraySize = 0;
        NoBuckets =0;
        // Statistics

        SSAverageAccessTime       = 0;
        SSAverageCompSuc          = 0;
        SSAverageCompFailed       = 0;
        SSNumberKeysSuc           = 0;
        SSNumberKeysFailed        = 0;




        BSAverageAccessTime       = 0;
        BSAverageCompSuc          = 0;
        BSAverageCompFailed       = 0;
        BSNumberKeysSuc           = 0;
        BSNumberKeysFailed        = 0;


        HSAverageAccessTime       = 0;
        HSAverageCompSuc          = 0;
        HSAverageCompFailed       = 0;
        HSNumberKeysSuc           = 0;
        HSNumberKeysFailed        = 0;




    }   


    public void ReadDataFile() throws IOException
    {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setDialogType(JFileChooser.OPEN_DIALOG );
        chooser.setDialogTitle("Open Data File");

        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if( returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
        {
            DataFilePath = chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();
            DataFileName = chooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
        }

        // read data file and copy it to original array
        if (DataFilePath != null)
        {
            try
            {

                int index = 0;
                Scanner integerTextFile = new Scanner(new File(DataFilePath));   
                while (integerTextFile.hasNext())
                {
                    // read the next integer
                    OriginalArray[index] = integerTextFile.nextInt();
                    index++;
                }
                //  end of file detected
                integerTextFile.close();
                NumberOfDataItems = index;
            }
            catch (IOException ioe)
            {
                System.exit(0); 
            }     

        }
        else
            NumberOfDataItems = 0;
    }
    public void ReadKeysFile() throws IOException
    {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setDialogType(JFileChooser.OPEN_DIALOG );
        chooser.setDialogTitle("Open Keys File");

        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if( returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
        {
            KeysFilePath = chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();
            KeysFileName = chooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
        }
        // read data file and copy it to original array
        if (KeysFilePath != null)
        {
            try
            {
                int index = 0;
                Scanner integerTextFile = new Scanner(new File(KeysFilePath));   
                while (integerTextFile.hasNext())
                {
                    // read the next integer
                    KeysArray[index]= integerTextFile.nextInt();
                    index++;
                }
                //  end of file detected
                integerTextFile.close();
                NumberOfKeys = index;
            }
            catch (IOException ioe)
            {
                System.exit(0); 
            }     

        }
        else
            NumberOfKeys = 0;
    }
    public void SequentialSearch() 
    {
        SSAverageAccessTime     = 0;
        SSAverageCompSuc        = 0;
        SSAverageCompFailed     = 0;
        SSNumberKeysSuc         = 0;
        SSNumberKeysFailed      = 0;
        int SearchKey;
        int TotalNumberOfComparisons;
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        boolean found = false;

        for (int k=0; k<NumberOfKeys; k++)
        {
            found = false;
            SearchKey = KeysArray[k];
            TotalNumberOfComparisons = 0;
            for (int d=0; d<NumberOfDataItems; d++)
            {
                TotalNumberOfComparisons++;
                if (SearchKey == OriginalArray[d])
                {
                    found = true;
                }
                if (found)break;
            }
            if(found)
            {
                SSAverageCompSuc = SSAverageCompSuc + TotalNumberOfComparisons;
                SSNumberKeysSuc ++;
            }
            else
            {
                SSAverageCompFailed = SSAverageCompFailed + TotalNumberOfComparisons;
                SSNumberKeysFailed ++;
            }
        }
        long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;

        if (NumberOfKeys != 0)
            SSAverageAccessTime = Math.round((estimatedTime/NumberOfKeys));
        else
            SSAverageAccessTime = 0;
        if(SSNumberKeysSuc != 0)
            SSAverageCompSuc        = Math.round (SSAverageCompSuc / SSNumberKeysSuc) ;
        else
            SSAverageCompSuc        = 0;
        if (SSNumberKeysFailed != 0)
            SSAverageCompFailed     = Math.round (SSAverageCompFailed / SSNumberKeysFailed) ;
        else
            SSNumberKeysFailed = 0;
        return;
    }


    public void BinarySearch() 
    {
        BSAverageAccessTime     = 0 ;
        BSAverageCompSuc        = 0 ;
        BSAverageCompFailed     = 0 ;
        BSNumberKeysSuc         = 0 ;
        BSNumberKeysFailed      = 0 ;
        int SearchKey;
        int TotalNumberOfComparisons;

        boolean found = false;

        for (int i=0; i<NumberOfDataItems; i++)
        {
            SortedArray[i] = OriginalArray[i];
        }

        Arrays.sort(SortedArray);

        long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        for (int k=0; k<NumberOfKeys; k++)
        {
            found = false;
            SearchKey = KeysArray[k];
            TotalNumberOfComparisons = 0;


            //binary starts

            int start = 0;
            int end = SortedArray.length - 1;
            int middle;

            while ( end >= start )
            {
                middle = ( start + end )/ 2;                       // element in middle of array


                if ( SortedArray[middle] == SearchKey )

                {
                    TotalNumberOfComparisons++;
                    found = true; 

                }  
                else 
                    if ( SortedArray[middle] > SearchKey )
                    { TotalNumberOfComparisons++;
                    end = middle - 1;


                    }                           // search left side of array
                    else
                    {  TotalNumberOfComparisons++;
                    start = middle + 1; }                          // search right side of array

                if (found)
                    break;
                //binaryends
            }

            if(found)
            {
                BSAverageCompSuc = BSAverageCompSuc + TotalNumberOfComparisons;
                BSNumberKeysSuc ++;
            }
            else
            {
                BSAverageCompFailed = BSAverageCompFailed + TotalNumberOfComparisons;
                BSNumberKeysFailed ++;
            }
        }

        long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;

        if (NumberOfKeys != 0)
            BSAverageAccessTime = Math.round((estimatedTime/NumberOfKeys));
        else
            BSAverageAccessTime = 0;
        if(BSNumberKeysSuc != 0)
            BSAverageCompSuc        = Math.round (BSAverageCompSuc / BSNumberKeysSuc) ;
        else
            BSAverageCompSuc        = 0;
        if (BSNumberKeysFailed != 0)
            BSAverageCompFailed     = Math.round (BSAverageCompFailed / BSNumberKeysFailed) ;
        else
            BSNumberKeysFailed = 0;
        return;
    }





    public void HashedSearch() 
    {
        HSAverageAccessTime       = 0;
        HSAverageCompSuc          = 0;
        HSAverageCompFailed       = 0;
        HSNumberKeysSuc           = 0;
        HSNumberKeysFailed        = 0;

        Initialize();

        int SearchKey;
        int TotalNumberOfComparisons;
        int address;
        int M;
        M = FindPrime();


        for(int i=0; i<NumberOfDataItems; i++)
        {

            address = OriginalArray[i] % M; 
            if (HashedArray[address]== -1)
                HashedArray[address]= OriginalArray[i];
            else 

            {
                address = (address+1) % M;

                while(HashedArray[address]!=-1)
                {

                    address=(address+1)%M;

                }

                HashedArray[address]=OriginalArray[i];

            }

        }

        System.out.println("after mapping" + M);
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        boolean found = false;

        for (int k = 0; k <NumberOfKeys; k++)
        { 

            found = false;
            SearchKey = KeysArray[k];
            TotalNumberOfComparisons = 0;


            address = KeysArray[k] % M;             
            //System.out.println("address" + address);

                //System.out.println(" inside if 1 --- address" + address);
            while ( HashedArray[address]!= SearchKey && HashedArray[address]!= -1)
            {
                if (HashedArray [address] == SearchKey)
                {
                    found = true;
                    TotalNumberOfComparisons++;
                    HSAverageCompSuc = HSAverageCompSuc + TotalNumberOfComparisons;
                    BSNumberKeysSuc ++;
                }
                else 
                {


                    System.out.println("Stuck after here");
                    HSAverageCompFailed = HSAverageCompFailed + TotalNumberOfComparisons;
                    HSNumberKeysFailed ++;

                        //address=(address+1)%M; 
                    address++;
                    }

                    System.out.println(" outside while --- found" + found);

                    //if(HashedArray[address] == SearchKey)
                        //found = true;
                    //else found = false;

                    //address=(address+1)%M;
                    //address++;
                }

            if(found)
            {
                HSAverageCompSuc = HSAverageCompSuc + TotalNumberOfComparisons;
                BSNumberKeysSuc ++;
            }
            else
            {
                HSAverageCompFailed = HSAverageCompFailed + TotalNumberOfComparisons;
                HSNumberKeysFailed ++;
            }
        }

        long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;

        if (NumberOfKeys != 0)
            HSAverageAccessTime = Math.round((estimatedTime/NumberOfKeys));
        else
            HSAverageAccessTime = 0;
        if(HSNumberKeysSuc != 0)
            HSAverageCompSuc        = Math.round (HSAverageCompSuc / HSNumberKeysSuc) ;
        else
            HSAverageCompSuc        = 0;
        if (HSNumberKeysFailed != 0)
            HSAverageCompFailed     = Math.round (HSAverageCompFailed / HSNumberKeysFailed) ;
        else
            HSNumberKeysFailed = 0;
        System.out.println("time after search" + estimatedTime);
        return; 
    } 



    public int FindPrime()
    {
        boolean prime = true;

        for(int i=NumberOfDataItems * 2-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
            System.out.println(" i = " +i);

            prime = true;
            for(int J =2; J< Math.sqrt(i); J++)
            {
                if (i % J == 0)
                {
                    prime = false;

                }
                if (prime == false) break;
            }
            if (prime == true)
            {
                System.out.println(i);
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;  
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {

        for (int i=0; i<NumberOfDataItems; i++)
        {
            HashedArray[i] = -1;
        }

    }
    public void BHSearch()
    {


    }

}
```